Re-open last closed tab (undo tab close)
In VS Code, if I accidentally close a tab, how do I reopen it? Like how in most browsers, I can press Cmd+Shift+T to undo closing a tab.

Press Cmd+Shift+T (on Mac) or Ctrl+Shift+T (on Windows/Linux) to re-open the last closed tab. This will trigger the workbench.action.reopenClosedEditor command.
